# error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting this error:

```
main.cpp:31: error: no matching function for call to 'QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject(QString, Eh*&)'
candidates are: void QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject(const QString&, QObject*)
```

This is the source code:

```
#include <string>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QGraphicsWebView>
#include <QWebPage>
#include "html5applicationviewer.h"

class Eh
{
    int lol()
    {
        return 666;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Html5ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(Html5ApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.showExpanded();
    viewer.loadFile(QLatin1String("html/index.html"));

    QWebPage *page = viewer.webView()->page();
    QWebFrame *frame = page->mainFrame();

    Eh *s = new Eh();

    frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject(QString("test"), s);

    return app.exec();
}
```

I've tried giving a new instance of `Eh` and the `Eh` class itself. In both cases it fails. Also I can't give the non-pointer of it since new returns a pointer.

My question is this: why is it `Eh*&` and not `Eh*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addToJavaScriptWindowObject` takes a `QObject*` as its second parameter. So you need to have `Eh` inherit from `QObject`.

Try something like this:

```
class Eh : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Eh(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
    }

    int lol() {
        return 666;
    }
};
```

Comment: So the problem is not the `&` character?

Comment: @Evan Teran: I think the OP's Q is not about why the error, it is about why the specific wrong error message.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: @Als: you may be right, but he did write this: "I've tried giving a new instance of Eh and the Eh class itself." My correction should resolve the compiler error. Why the compiler includes a ref during the attempt to match the function is another (much more interesting) question though.

Comment: @Evan Teran: Okay, Actually, Why the specific error seemed so interesting I totally missed out whether OP was not only asking about that but also resolving the error.

Comment: Yea, the question is kinda two fold.