# Why the Compiler does not detect correct function signature in error?

Tags: c++, function, gcc

The question is in reference to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111442/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to/)**, which was posted a little while earlier.
While the OP was happy accepting the answer which solved his problem I was a little intrigued with a detail as to why compiler gave a seemingly wrong error.

Below is a small code sample I created to demonstrate the same:

```
    class YourClass
    {
    };

    class YourClass2
    {
    };
    class MyClass
    {
        public:
            void doSomething(YourClass2 obj)
            {
                //Nothing more Interesting to do
            }

    };

    int main()
    {
        YourClass *ptr = new YourClass();
        MyClass obj;
        obj.doSomething(ptr);

        return 0;
    }
```

Compiling **[this](http://www.ideone.com/4nUpf)** with **GCC(4.3.4)** gives a seemingly strange error result:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::doSomething(YourClass*&)’
prog.cpp:13: note: candidates are: void MyClass::doSomething(YourClass2)
```

---

**So the Question is:**
Why does the compiler treat the call,

```
obj.doSomething(ptr);
```

as call to a function with prototype,

```
MyClass::doSomething(YourClass*&)
```

and not

```
MyClass::doSomething(YourClass*)
```

which seems to be the obvious case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have stated, the compiler is trying to be helpful, and probably confusing you. Lets start with the simplest error:

> error: no matching function for call to `obj.doSomething(ptr)`

While the error message is correct, the information that it provides is very limited. In this example the code is simple to follow, but consider a more complex piece of code. You read the error message and you may think... *what's obj?, what's ptr?* So it tries to help you and tells you what `obj` is:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::doSomething(ptr)’

Well, that's better, it is telling you at least in what class you need to look for the overload, but consider that the class was `std::ostream` and the function `operator<<`... there are just too many overloads, and still, what is the type of `ptr`? So it moves forward and tries to describe the argument: The argument is an *lvalue* of type `YourClass*`... and I have seen that type of error message produced in the past:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::doSomething’ that takes an `YourClass*` lvalue as argument.

Ok, so the error report is complete. Now think that the function might have more arguments, and the error message can turn into a complex beast (imagine a list of 5 "rvalue of type XXX and an lvalue of type YYY and ..."). The next thing is making the syntax of the error message just as precise (the *lvalue*-ness of the argument is important, or the *rvalue*-ness would be important, so that piece of information has to be present). So it rewrites the error message again:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::doSomething(YourClass*&)’

The problem is that you are trying to interpret that as a function signature, but it is rather the description of the function call.

Error messages are not defined in the standard, and they differ from one compiler to another, even from one version to another within the same compiler. At the end of the day you need to learn to *read* the error messages and what they mean.

Comment: +1. I liked the step by step analysis of the compiler message. :-). And the most important point being `The problem is that you are trying to interpret that as a function signature, but it is rather the description of the function call.`

Answer (score 6):

First, note that the *expression* `ptr` (not the *variable* `ptr`) has type `YourClass *&`. This is important; it's the only way reference types can work (otherwise you'd be making a reference to a *copy* when you do `YourClass *&x = ptr`, and it's also why `YourClass *&x = (ptr + 1)` fails). As such, the compiler starts its search for a function with `MyClass::doSomething(YourClass *&)`.

Of course, this call can match a prototype `MyClass::doSomething(YourClass *)`. It can also match `MyClass::doSomething(const YourClass *)` or many others. There's potentially dozens (or, with multiple parameters, easily hundreds or thousands) of prototypes that could potentially match this call; however, none could be found.

So the compiler gives up, and gives an error. In the error, rather listing every theoretically possible match, it cites the one prototype that most closely matches what it was originally looking for; that is, `MyClass::doSomething(YourClass *&)`.

Comment: How is the first signature the most general one? I'd think that's the one with an implicit conversion, rather than the second.

Comment: @bdonlan: Well, it begs another question: why the compiler searches like that? Does the stardard requires it that way?

Comment: While you can do a conversion from Foo to Foo&, that implies that a copy would be forced even if a reference would otherwise be possible.

Comment: @bdonlan: Then the Q is, Why would the compiler search for `MyClass::doSomething(YourClass *&)` when the function being called has the signature `MyClass::doSomething(YourClass *)`? Do you mean the compiler looks up for fixed patterns of function signatures rather than the actual ones being called through code.

Comment: @Nawaz, I don't have a copy of the standard on-hand, but basically, it has to try various combinations of annotations (constness, volatile, reference-to etc) that values can decay to. Listing out every possibility would make C++ errors (which are already quite verbose) far too long.

Comment: @Als, the function being called does not have a signature `(YourClass *)`. You passed in a reference to a pointer (ie, the _expression_ `ptr` has type `YourClass *&`). If all it could find was a raw pointer `(YourClass *)`, it would convert that reference-to-pointer to a pointer and pass that.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is trying to be helpful.

```
MyClass::doSomething(YourClass*&)
```

This does not name any function:  there is no function in your code that matches this.

`YourClass*&` is the type of the argument you are trying to pass to a function named `MyClass::doSomething`:  the argument (`ptr`) is an lvalue, represented in the error by the `&`.

The compiler needs some way to distinguish lvalue arguments from rvalue arguments in order to provide you with as much useful diagnostic information as possible; this is one succinct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is not required to generate message which should make sense to you. All that it needs to tell you that there is an error in your code. Now what messages it prints, is upto the compiler. The Standard doesn't say what message it should print, and what not. When the compiler prints error message, that error message can be either good/helpful, or bad/unhelpful, but not "wrong", in my opinion.

Comment: I do know that, The Question is, the compiler needs no special effort to detect that function signature and yet it gives a diagnostic message which does not match, Question is Why?