# Nested Pass by Reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I need to have a nested pass by reference.

**EDITED TO INCLUDE ACTUAL CODE**

Exact error is:

> no matching function for call to ‘CLItem::getValue(std::string*&)’

Complete error is:

```
App/CycCmdLine.cpp: In member function ‘std::string CycCmdLine::getEnvironment()’:
App/CycCmdLine.cpp:245: error: no matching function for call to ‘CycCmdLine::getValue(const char [16], std::string&)’
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h: In member function ‘bool CmdLine::getValue(std::string, T&) [with T = std::string*]’:
App/CycCmdLine.cpp:384:   instantiated from here
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h:237: error: no matching function for call to ‘CLItem::getValue(std::string*&)’
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h:145: note: candidates are: bool CLItem::getValue(bool&)
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h:146: note:                 bool CLItem::getValue(std::string&)
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h:147: note:                 bool CLItem::getValue(long unsigned int&)
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h:148: note:                 bool CLItem::getValue(std::list<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h:149: note:                 bool CLItem::getValue(std::list<std::list<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::list<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&)
```

Updated code:

```
// initial caller
string CycCmdLine::getEnvironment()
{
    string sRet="";
    do
    {     
        if(hasLogFile())
            {
                string sLogFile="";
                getValue(CYCCMD_CMDSTR_LOGFILE, sLogFile);
                sRet+="\n  -Profiler logfile: "+sLogFile;
            }
    }while(false);
    return(sRet);
}

// CmdLine::getValue function definition (this is in the header file, as a template should be)
template <typename T>
bool CmdLine::getValue(string sName, T &tValue)
{
    bool bRet=false;
    do
    {
    // try to get the iterator
    bool bExists;
    map<string, CLItem*>::iterator itItr;
    bExists=getMapElement(sName, itItr);

        // go ahead and return the value
        if(!itItr->second->getValue(tValue)) { break; }
        bRet=true;
    }while(false);
    return(bRet);
}

bool CLItem::getValue(string& sValue)
{
    bool bRet=false;
    do
    {
        // is this the correct type?
        if(!isType(CLType_STRING)) { break; }

        // return the value
        sValue=m_sValue;
        bRet=true;
    }while(false);
    return(bRet);
}
```

Comment: OK -- so it IS more complicated then I thought. That is good news to some degree. I'm bringing over real code now.

Comment: @Bo Persson, I've updated with the "actual code", although I've scraped some components out..

Comment: what's the purpose of do{} while( false ) ?

Comment: how do you instantiate template? is it something like  CmdLine<string> ?

Comment: @stijn, It is referred to as coding by contract. If any part of the "contract" is not met, we break out of this loop. The team which I work on utilizes this paradigm. Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Comment: @alexm, I've added code which shows the initial call made to getValue()

Comment: -1 the code doesn't match the problem description.

Comment: You could get the message if `T` is actually `std::string*` somewhere in the code calling the first function. Here it is assumed that `T` is `string` to match the call of getValue.

Comment: @BSchlinker: This is not design by contract. In design by contract you check, pre-, and postconditions, and invariants. You don't have this here.. and certainly not with do while..

Comment: @BSchlinker This is not design-by-contract, this is a mess. Using bool returns to signal contract fulfilment and managing everything else through non-const references is simply language abuse.

Comment: @stijn - the do-while-break is a way to "avoid" multiple returns by doing a break instead. It's debatable if this is avoiding or hiding.

Comment: I understand that there are objections to the "style" of this code -- this is why I did not post the actual code initially. I was asked to post the actual code and I did. I did not write the code standards for this project (they were written months before I was hired), so I do not have much to defend them with...

Comment: @BSchlinker: of course you're right, you have to obey some coding standard. That's fine. But you're link referring to design by contract couldn't be further from the truth. :) I just wanted to tell you that, I didn't want to critize this "style", since it doesn't have anything to do with the actual question. Let's discuss your actual problem hehe :)

Comment: Also look at this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111843/why-the-compiler-does-not-detect-correct-function-signature-in-error/7112815#7112815)

Comment: What happens if you call it using `getValue<string>(CYCCMD_CMDSTR_LOGFILE, sLogFile)` instead?

Comment: @carlpett, Yep -- it works then. I have to make the change in about 200 locations which is why I wanted to verify first. Why is it necessary to specify the <string> like this? I know when I use a templated class it is needed, but doesn't the compiler have sufficient information from the call itself?

Comment: I should note here -- although I DID change the code with a quick find/replace to see if carlpett's solution worked, I would not have left it without first understanding why it was required. Hence, my question above..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look into this part of the message

```
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h: In member function ‘bool CmdLine::getValue(std::string, T&) [with T = std::string*]’:
App/CycCmdLine.cpp:384:   instantiated from here
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h:237: error: no matching function for call to ‘CLItem::getValue(std::string*&)’
```

It seems to say that at`App/CycCmdLine.cpp:384` you call getValue with `T` being a `std::string*`. This then causes the template to try to call a function that doesn't exist.

Start investigating this line 384!

Comment: Bo, carlpett in the comments above seems to have isolated the error.

Comment: I think he's treating the symptoms, not the illness.

Comment: @BSchlinker: Bo is right, specifying that you want to call a template will solve the symptom, but the problems are somewhere else. The first problem is that the compiler is not finding a match to the call in line 245, the second one is that code in 384 is passing the wrong argument (`std::string*`). Unless you fully understand what is causing the error and why explicitly stating the template specialization helps, I would not just blindly start changing the code.

Comment: Overall, part of the problem here seems to be confusion within the compiler. I took Bo's advice above and took a look at like 384. Look at that -- in this one function, I WAS passing a pointer to the getValue method. Clearing this issue up resolved all of the other issues, including the issue you have noted above on line #245, without any other modifications.

Why did the compiler mention this error then on line #245? I do not know. I ONLY changed line #384... but I would love to know why the compiler got "confused" or if I am missing something here.

Comment: @BSchlinker - If you pass different parameter types to a template, the compiler will create two different functions. If you now pass the same types in all calls, there will only be one getValue function. The one that works, obviously!

Answer (score 2):

You can reproduce that error with this code.

```
#include <string>

struct X
{
    void foo(std::string& n)
    {
    }

    void bar()
    {
       std::string* s;
       foo(s);
    }
};


prog.cpp: In member function ‘void X::bar()’:
prog.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘X::foo(std::string*&)’
prog.cpp:5: note: candidates are: void X::foo(std::string&)
```

The suggested reference symbol is not very significant. You are indeed trying to pass a pointer where a value is expected, and the compiler is guessing what a suitable function for that call might look like. (It probably means that you are passing a lvalue, so the function might take it by reference.)

Also note that it lists candidates, functions by the same name but with unsuitable parameter types.

---

Now that you've posted real code, perhaps check what the template type is in your faulty instantiation (the error message should mention that too).

---

Now that you have also posted error messages:

```
App/CycCmdLine.cpp: In member function ‘std::string CycCmdLine::getEnvironment()’:
App/CycCmdLine.cpp:245: error: no matching function for call to ‘CycCmdLine::getValue(const char [16], std::string&)’
```

This is the first error. Translation: the class CycCmdLine doesn't have a member function `getValue` (nor is there a global function by this name). A function by that name is a member of `CmdLine`.

```
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h: In member function ‘bool CmdLine::getValue(std::string, T&) [with T = std::string*]’:
App/CycCmdLine.cpp:384:   instantiated from here
./../CmdLine/CmdLine.h:237: error: no matching function for call to ‘CLItem::getValue(std::string*&)’
```

This is the second error, the one you are asking about. You are passing a pointer-to-string on line 384 of `CycCmdLine.cpp` (which is in a different place than you thought).

Comment: My initial call though (which I now include above) does not contain a pointer. I initialize a string and then pass it to the first function.

Comment: Yes -- ok, you are right. "In member function ‘bool CmdLine::getValue(std::string, T&) [with T = std::string*]’:" However, I'm not sure why it is using that template. Perhaps there is something I do not understand about templated functions, as I have only used templated classes in the past.

Comment: @BSchlinker: What does the exact call (that fails) look like and how is the second argument type declared?

Comment: @UncleBen, I will update that in a moment. I appreciate your help. My apologizes for not posting everything initially. I (correctly) predicted though that a comment war would erupt regarding the style of this code and tried to avoid that.

Comment: @UncleBen, you can now see the complete hierarchy of a call (not all the way from main of course.. but there is no longer any floating code..)

Comment: @BSchlinker: Are you sure that is the exact code? In the code you presented the argument `T` is a `std::string` but the compiler is complaining because it thinks that the argument `T` is a `std::string*`...

Comment: @BSchlinker: It seems that you have **two** errors there. First is that you are apparently confusing `CycCmdLine` and `CmdLine` (the `string*` error doesn't come from the call, because that call itself cannot be resolved), and somewhere else you have a call where you pass the string pointer. - But I'm off to work now.

Comment: @David, Yes, this is exact code. Your comment is my question -- why does that occur?

Comment: @BSchilinker: When fixing compiler errors, start from the very first one, which in your case says that `getValue(CYCCMD_CMDSTR_LOGFILE, sLogFile);` cannot be matched to a function call. Damn it! **Please provide full error messages** (or at least start from the beginning).