# C++ std::list of pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, list, pointers, struct, std

I believe it's a very easy question but I'm quite confused.

What I am doing wrong ?:

```
    std::list<curvesdata *> curvelist;
    curvesdata * curve = new curvesdata;

    curvelist.pop_back(curve);

   ---> no matching function for call to 'std::list<curvesdata*>::pop_back(curvesdata*&)
```

Seems my pointer is converted to a pointer reference ... ? why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void pop_back ( );
```

Does not take any arguments. It removes the last element in the list container, effectively reducing the list size by one.  See the reference **[here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/pop_back/)**.

Since the function does not take any arguments, the compiler tries to tell you the same by giving the error of non matching function.
To know Why the compiler does not report the exact error, see this:

**[why-the-compiler-does-not-detect-correct-function-signature-in-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111843/why-the-compiler-does-not-detect-correct-function-signature-in-error)**

---

To Add a new element at the end of the list,You should be using:

```
list::push_back()
```

To Add a new element at the front of the list, You should be using:

```
list::push_front()
```

See the reference **[here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/push_back/)**.

Answer (score 0):

`std::list::pop_back()` doesn't take an argument, it deletes the last element from the list. Looks like you want to add, so use `push_back()`.

`curvelist.push_back(curve);`

edit: Now let me wax on about clang++ and its nicer error messages:

```
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> x;
    x.pop_back(1);
}


$ clang++ example.cxx 
example.cxx:6:13: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1
        x.pop_back(1);
        ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. There's no member function called `pop_back` for list that takes an argument.

You may be thinking of `push_back`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/push_back/

Comment: @birryree: Edited my question. I trailed off my sentence without fully finishing the thought. The error is perfectly clear in that it's stating that no such function exist which takes an argument.

Comment: it could stand to be clearer, like with clang's front end. For beginners to a language it would be much tougher to figure out as it's not obvious. Anyway, I'll remove my first comment. :)

Comment: @birryree: Completely agree on the front that practically all C++ compilers have horrible error messages. Personally, I quite like the helpful error messages from Ada.

Answer (score 0):

`pop_back()` doesn't take an argument. There's no matching call to what you're trying to do.