# c++ "no matching function to call

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing

When trying to pass in an array as a param I get:

```
"No matching function to call to ' table::retrieve(const char[16], item&, int)'
```

I am trying to call the function with

```
program.reference.retrieve("Abecean Longfin", program.client_item, 1);
```

the function is

```
int table::retrieve(char item_in[],item*item_list, int name_flag)
```

I'm sure this is something simple I don't understand, but I'm new to it.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned it, but an `std::string` would be a better option, including more familiarities. If `item_list` is to be used as an array, `std::vector` would work well for that.

Answer (score 5):

The real reason your call is failing is because you're passing an `item&` where your function takes an `item*`. Your code *also* violates const correctness on the string, but in C++03 they have a special rule which makes that legal.

Comment: Come on DeadMG, elaborate a little on why it is being passed as & instead of *

Comment: How the hell should I know? The code shown only says two things: it's an `item&` and the prototype is `item*`.

Comment: While this seems to be the real reason.How do you know it's an `item&`? Diagnostic messages need not give the real function signature.

Comment: @Als: Whether it's a value or a reference is immaterial. What's important is that it is not a pointer.

Comment: He needs to put a damn & on the front of it, program.reference.retrieve("Abecean Longfin", &program.client_item, 1);

Comment: Actually, if he treats it like an array, that's fairly bound to failure.

Comment: Thank you, between this and another answer that cleared it up.  Appreciate it

Comment: @Als: It's a reference, the error message gives a "direct" function match (that's why it says `const char[16]`, for example); it also shows an `item&`.

Comment: Sure is immaterial but I just wanted to point out that cannot be absolutely sure enough to say *"you're passing an `item&`"*. Its a *nitpick* I agree but a valid one.

Comment: I have a client_list I meant to pass in, for some reason I thought I could pass in an single item the same way

Comment: @Als: Not really, because the fix is identical, so it's absolutely immaterial and irrelevant.

Comment: @GManNickG: I have not compiled the code sample myself, So I don't know if it is a *direct* match error but [diagnostic error messages do not always detect correct function signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111843/why-the-compiler-does-not-detect-correct-function-signature-in-error)

Comment: @Als: Nobody is arguing with you about diagnostic messages being dependent on quality of implementation, we're simply saying that almost certainly he's not passing a reference. Surely you don't think in total certainty all the time? You even said: "This seems to be the real reason." The purpose of this site is indeed to give solutions to what seems to be the problem.

Comment: @GManNickG: I am not even arguing that the fix and the solution is not valid.I even said that my comment is a *nitpick*, true the site is to give solutions,but also to help people learn.The answer doesn't say *probably* it says *You are passing a ref* For someone asking an Q of this very nature, it might be confusing.I just wanted to point out the obvious fact, nothing more nothing less.There is nothing to prove here, this is the correct answer just it could be worded better to avoid confusion.And I think comments are rather constructive way to make answers better if taken in the right spirit.